# How to test a Padrino controller from Padrino console

Tags: ruby, controller, sinatra, padrino

I know in Rails I can do something like

```
app.get 'url'
app.response
```

But this does not work in Padrino, nor do any of the regular `controller` calls because Padrino uses different controller methods than Rails.

What I'm trying to do is test my controller methods from the Ruby Padrino MRI console. For example, I want to store the objects present, call the same method 100 times, then compare what objects are left behind. I'm trying to find a memory leak.

So it would be great to be able to call the method from a Padrino `console`.

I can't find anything that tells me how to do it in the official documentation or elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `get` in you Padrino::Application is just part of the DSL to define new routes, not to retrieve their contents. What you are trying to achieve is usually part of the Rack::Test library.

Have a look at the Sinatra documentation:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html

Specially compare the sections about Rack::Test with Mixin VS without Mixin. That should make you understand where the *fetching get* comes from.

In your case, if you want to test from the console, then it should be something like this part:

```
require 'rack/test'
browser = Rack::Test::Session.new(Rack::MockSession.new(Padrino::Application))
browser.get '/'
```

Now, where you see `Padrino::Application` you must type your own application main class that inherits from that class, not the abstract class itself

Notice that the result will be a Rack::MockSession object, so if you just want to see the html do:

```
browser.get('/').body
```